# ffplay is not getting compiled on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ffmpeg

Asking this question as similar questions of stackoverflow didn't help me.

I wanted to install ffplay tool on my Amazon EC2 (Linux) instance. I have cloned the code from FFmpeg's official [git repository](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git).

executed ./configure and make. After these commands, there was no ffplay binary created. Only ffmpeg, ffprobe and ffserver binaries were generated.

Later tried with executing './configure --enable-ffplay' as suggested in few posts of web. Even this didn't work. Also i did not found any static binaries of ffplay which i could use for my testing

Can anyone suggest what was wrong with my build procedure ?

Answer (score 3):

`ffplay` requires SDL2, so you need to install whatever package provides `SDL.h` (possibly **SDL2-devel** for RHEL based distros or **libsdl2-dev** for Debian based distors), or [compile SDL2](https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation#Linux.2FUnix) if your distro does not provide it.

You won't need `--enable-ffplay`: that's only useful if you use `--disable-tools` or similar.

Comment: Thanks. Running `sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev` and configuring ffmpeg again automatically installed ffplay for me

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar issue [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/6880). But this could be used as reference.

Try these out:

1. Try installing SDL2 from RHEL or Debian distribution.
2. Try using `--with-ffplay` instead of `--enable-ffplay` as mentioned in the link above.

Comment: `--with-ffplay` looks like a Homebrew specific option: it's not an option used by FFmpeg at all, and I don't think EC2 offers macOS. `--enable-ffplay` does nothing useful unless a disable option has been used (as mentioned in my answer).

Comment: Unknown option "--with-ffplay".
See ./configure --help for available options.